# NodeJS - read CSV file to array returns []

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the promised-csv module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/promised-csv) to read the rows of a CSV file to an array of strings for a unit test:

```
const inputFile = '.\\test\\example_result.csv';
const CsvReader = require('promised-csv');

function readCSV(inputFile){
   var reader = new CsvReader();
   var output = [];
   reader.on('row', function (data) {
       //console.log(data);
       output.push(data[0]);
   });

  reader.read(inputFile, output);
  return output;
}
```

I would like to call this function later in a unit test.

```
it("Should store the elements of the array", async () => {
   var resultSet = readCSV(inputFile);
   console.log(resultSet);
});
```

However, resultSet yields an empty array. I am also open to use any other modules, as long as I can get an array of strings as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look something like this, according to the docs.

```
const inputFile = './test/example_result.csv';
const CsvReader = require('promised-csv');

function readCSV(inputFile) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var reader = new CsvReader();
        var output = [];

        reader.on('row', data => {
            // data is an array of data. You should
            // concatenate it to the data set to compile it.
            output = output.concat(data);
        });

        reader.on('done', () => {
            // output will be the compiled data set.
            resolve(output);
        });

        reader.on('error', err => reject(err));

        reader.read(inputFile);

    });
}

it("Should store the elements of the array", async () => {
    var resultSet = await readCSV(inputFile);
    console.log(resultSet);
});
```

Comment: I assume so from the documents, but I didn't test it, so I can't be sure. I will test the code myself and update shortly.

Comment: Based on my testing with a sample `.csv` file, simply using `CsvReader.prototype.read()`, does not return a `Promise` with the expected data. You must use the `EventEmitter` interface as is defined in https://www.npmjs.com/package/promised-csv#using-the-eventemitter-interface, and return your own promise with the compiled data set.

Comment: Made a few updates to take into consideration how the data is presented in the `'row'` event.

Answer (score 0):

`readCSV()` returns a Promise.  There are two ways that you can access the data it returns upon completion.

1. As Roland Starke suggests, use `async` and `await`.

`var resultSet = await readCSV(inputFile);`
This will wait for the Promise to resolve before returning a value.

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

2. Use `Promise.prototype.then()` - this is similar to async/await, but can also be chained with other promises and `Promise.prototype.catch()`.
   The most important thing to remember is that the function passed to `.then()` will not be executed until `readCSV()` has resolved.

`readCSV().then((data)=>{return data}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})`

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then